# Are multicolor polylines possible with leaflet

Tags: javascript, maps, gis, leaflet

I have a list of `LatLng` including some additional data (e.g. altitude/elevation) and I would like to display them with [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com) as a `Polyline`. Instead of a single colored line I would like to have the line colored according to that additional data though.

Is that possible with leaflet at all? Do plugins exist for something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several plugins to do this. For example this one:
https://github.com/hgoebl/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var states = [{
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {"altitude": "high"},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
        [-104.05, 48.99],
        [-97.22,  48.98],
        [-96.58,  45.94],
        [-104.03, 45.94],
        [-104.05, 48.99]
    ]]
}
}, {
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {"altitude": "low"},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
        [-109.05, 41.00],
        [-102.06, 40.99],
        [-102.03, 36.99],
        [-109.04, 36.99],
        [-109.05, 41.00]
    ]]
}
}];
L.geoJson(states, {
style: function(feature) {
    switch (feature.properties.altitude) {
        case 'high': return {color: "#ff0000"};
        case 'low':   return {color: "#0000ff"};
    }
}
}).addTo(map);
```

See [this](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) for more information.